# WebClient can't download string

Tags: c#, webclient

Why does this not works -

**"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly"**

```
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://oz.by/books/more10176026.html"));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

Usual GET requests are OK. check it [here](http://oz.by/books/more10176026.html)

Comment: Can you use a web debugger like Fiddler and check what's going on with the request? That would probably give a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The server seems to choke because there is no User Agent header. This fixes it:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    try
    {
        //Add your user agent of choice. This is mine, just as an example.
        client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_1) AppleWebKit/537.73.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/7.0.1 Safari/537.73.11");
        Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://oz.by/books/more10176026.html"));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {

        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this works. I have followed msdn, and this was my mistake)) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=vs.110).aspx